# Android Obfuscated APK Issues

Tags: android, listview, obfuscation, android-proguard, android-build-flavors

I have a strange issue in generating signed APK with Pro-Guard enabled.
I am showing a list view with some items from server with text color as black. In debug release the list view showing with data without any issues. But in release mode the list view showing data with transparent color, the text color i am using black and setting the color in list view adapter class, because in release mode i can click the list view and select the list item but the item in list view is not visible.

[image]

The above image is in debug mode and showing list view properly.

[image]

The above image is in release mode.

Please note my Pro-Guard file

```
    -keep class in.apricotz.outlet.ui.adapter.ListBaseAdapter.**
       -keep class butterknife.** { *; }
       -dontwarn butterknife.internal.**
       -keep class **$$ViewBinder { *; }

      -keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
      @butterknife.* <fields>;
     }

    -keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    @butterknife.* <methods>;
   }
   -dontwarn org.apache.http.**
   -dontwarn okio.**
   -dontwarn retrofit2.**
   -keep class retrofit2.** { *; }
   -keepattributes Signature
   -keepattributes Exceptions
   -keepattributes *Annotation*

   -keepattributes RuntimeVisibleAnnotations
   -keepattributes RuntimeInvisibleAnnotations
   -keepattributes RuntimeVisibleParameterAnnotations
   -keepattributes RuntimeInvisibleParameterAnnotations
   -keepattributes EnclosingMethod
   -keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    @retrofit2.* <methods>;
   }

  -keepclasseswithmembers interface * {
    @retrofit2.* <methods>;
  }

  -keepattributes Signature
  -keepnames class org.apache.** {*;}
  -keep public class org.apache.** {*;}
  -keep public class org.apache.http.**{*;}
  -keep class rx.schedulers.Schedulers {
    public static <methods>;
   }
   -keep class rx.schedulers.ImmediateScheduler {
     public <methods>;
    }
   -keep class rx.schedulers.TestScheduler {
    public <methods>;
    }
   -keep class rx.schedulers.Schedulers {
    public static ** test();
   }
  -keepclassmembers class rx.internal.util.unsafe.*ArrayQueue*Field* {
    long producerIndex;
    long consumerIndex;
   }
  -keepclassmembers class rx.internal.util.unsafe.BaseLinkedQueueProducerNodeRef              {        long producerNode;
      long consumerNode;
  }
  -dontwarn rx.internal.util.**

  -dontusemixedcaseclassnames
  -dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
  -dontpreverify
  -verbose
  -ignorewarnings
  -repackageclasses ''
  -allowaccessmodification
  -optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*

  -dontwarn android.support.design.**
  -keep class android.support.design.** { *; }
  -keep interface android.support.design.** { *; }
  -keep public class android.support.design.R$* { *; }
  -keep public class * extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment
  -keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
    public static <fields>;
   }
```

I have been messed up with this issue for the last two days. In debug release the app is working perfectly without any issues. Please help me.

> Blockquote

Comment: I got the issue  i just missed proguard rule for model class that using GSON.

Answer (score 0):

can't actually find the root cause for you, but you can check:

the url to get data from server in release mode, does it response the empty item in list of items?

If you use the custom library from github, check Pro-Guard which author setup.

have you use the view holder object to hold view item for listview? set text color for textview by programming.

you can use recyclerview to replace listview.

check problems with ProGuard:
https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/project/android/sdk/android-sdk-linux/tools/proguard/docs/index.html#manual/troubleshooting.html

Comment: getting data from server. There are no issues with server communication and resulting data is also setting to listview (i can select data from list view).  Using view holder in listview and setting the textcolor programatically